# Utility to convert log4j.xml to log4j2.xml

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am looking for the utility to convert log4j.xml to log4j2.xml syntax is there any utility available

Answer (score 0):

At first I was going to respond that this cannot be done but it might be somewhat possible.

Log4j 2.13.0 added [experimental support](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html) for using Log4j 1.x configuration files. If your configuration is compatible, in theory you could start up an application using a Log4j 1.x configuration and then call getRootNode() on the AbstractConfiguration. The root node is very similar to a DOM tree so walking it and converting it to XML wouldn't be too hard. However, Log4j doesn't have a tool provided to do this. Contributions are welcome!